# Tkinter multiprocessing can't pickle

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to write a simple messenger app with Python and Tkinter. I'm listening to to a `UDPSock` to receive input. However as Tkinter's `mainloop()` blocks the thread, I cannot receive input with only one thread. I've tried to send a reference to the `Tkinter` GUI to the `Process` that loops and listens to input but I get a `Can't pickle 'tkapp' object` error. As the input is continuous and the `Tkinter` thread can't do anything else except run the `mainloop` to handle the GUI I cannot put the received input onto the GUI. Even if I use a `Pipe` the `Tkinter` thread is running the `mainloop` and so there is nowhere I can put a

```
while True:
    data = pipe_conn.recv()
    # do something with data
```

or anything.

Any help would be much appreciated!

My code:

```
-- imports --

class MessageApp():
    def __init__(self, root, host, conn, port=13000):
        # Setup GUI
        self.send_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        p = Process(target=self.recv, args=(conn,))

    def recv(self, conn):
        buff = 1024
        print('recvin')
        while True:
            (data, addr) = conn.recvfrom(buff)
            self.add_msg(addr + ": " + data)

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def add_msg(self, text):
        self.msgs.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.msgs.insert(INSERT, text + "\n")
        self.msgs.config(state=DISABLED)

    def send(self):
        self.add_msg(self.inpt.get())
        self.send_sock.sendto(self.inpt.get(), self.send_addr)
        self.inpt.delete(0, 'end')  

# ----------WHERE CAN I PUT THIS------------
def msg_listen(messenger, conn, port=13000):
    buff = 1024
    recv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    recv_sock.bind(('', port))
    while True:
        (data, addr) = recv_sock.recvfrom(buff)
        conn.send()
    recv_sock.close()
# ------------------------------------------

def msgr_init(conn):
    root = Tk()
    messenger = MessageApp(root, ip, conn)
    messenger.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    root = Tk(
    par_conn, chd_conn = Pipe(True)
    msg_proc = Process(target=msgr_init, args=(chd_conn,))
    msg_proc.start()
    msg_listen(messenger, par_conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered `Tkinter.after()` after reading the docs and it solved my problem.

Comment: How, what did it do? This isn't an answer, please tell more